# searching an array for relevant information

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array that looks like this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 1
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => 
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 2
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => 
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 3
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => 
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 4
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 5
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 6
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 7
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 8
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 9
            [production_title] => Televison Show
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => voice over
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 10
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 11
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 12
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 13
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 14
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 15
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 16
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => television
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [career_overview_id] => 17
            [production_title] => Production Title
            [production_role] => Role
            [production_director] => Director
            [production_company] => Production Company
            [production_producer_theartre] => 
            [production_project_type] => 
            [production_product] => 
            [production_agency] => 
            [production_type] => theartre
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 37
        )

)
```

I want to search through the array and if for example a production_type = "television" exists I want to show some HTML.

Can I do this without looping through the array?

In essence I want to do the following,

```
if key and value exists anywhere in array  
    do something;
```

I am in the end wanting to construct a list of production_types but only list 1 instance of each type if they exist in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Using a single call of the native function [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$tvInThere = array_filter(function ($e) {
  return isset($e['production_type']) &&  $e['production_type'] == 'television';
}, $arr) > 0;
```

Comment: +1 Agreed, I stand corrected on this as well.  This is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function array_key_exists() to determine if a key is in an array. Similarly, the function in_array() will output 'true' if a value is in an array.  However, these functions do not work recursively.  You will therefore have to do some manner of looping.

Answer (score 1):

You use a wrong construct for your data if you want to avoid iterating the array.

```
//function to search the set and stop on first hit
function exists_in_set (&$set, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($set as $row) {
        if (isset($row[$key]) && $row[$key] = $value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//now for your 
//  if key and value exists anywhere in array  
//      do something;
if (exists_in_set($set, $key, $value)) {
    //do something
}
```

*EDIT:* Why array_filter isnt the best solution

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Iterates over each value in the input array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

the array_filter iterates over each value, and thus will be slower on bigger sets, because it does not stop on the first hit.

And secondly since you dont want to iterate the set, assuming it is for performance, the anonymous callback function used in the array_filter method is a lot slower, this difference is more noticeable with systems like apc_cache, the function cannot be optimized and has to be executed as-is at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

While there are libraries that can do this, there is no *single*, *native* PHP function for a multidimensional array search.

However, it seems to me you'd have to loop over the array for output anyway. In which case, what's the problem with:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if ($item['production_type'] != 'television') {
    continue;
  }

  // output...
}
```

#### UPDATE

`array_filter()` does work in this case. Thanks **phihag**.

Comment: I assume the downvoter had a problem with my first statement. See update. I still feel if the user is looping for display, there's no point in pre-filtering the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($infoChunk in $yourBigAssArray){
    $search1 = array_search('Television Show', $infoChunk);
    $search2 = array_search('Mr Pink', $infoChunk);
    if ($search1 && $search2 
        && $search1 =='production_title' 
        && $search2 =='production_director'
    ){
        doShiz();
    }
}
```

Just another way of doing the same thing... FWIW I would just loop though, I'd imagine the performance would be better than the above example I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about requires looping. In your pseudocode the "anywhere in" is essentially a loop :).

If you want to avoid looping for some specific reason, you could do something like redundantly store you're data in dictionary type structures with useful keys - but this is not advisable.

If you're arrays are of reasonable size, a single loop isn't going to kill - so if you are worried about efficiency dont fret :).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to (but not the same as) `array_filter` you can solve the generic problem with a [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).

I've created a generic one that takes an array to iterate over and a callback function.

Iterators can be used in `foreach` and they behave pretty much the same like an array. A FilterIterator return only a subset of the elements, but the elements are not deleted:

```
class ArrayFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    private $it, $filter;
    public function __construct(array $array, $filter)
    {
        $this->it = new ArrayIterator($array);
        $this->filter = $filter;
        parent::__construct($this->it);
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        $func = $this->filter;
        return $func($this->it->current());
    }
}

$filter = function($v){ return $v['production_type'] == "television";};

$it = new ArrayFilterIterator($array, $filter);

foreach($it as $entry)
{
    print_r($entry);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ELvNua)

Iterators are very powerful, because you can more easily change your code later on by just switching the filter.